# Bootstrap collapsing all Read More's at once

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a section with several paragraphs you can expand to read more or less. How do i differ them with pure bootstrap css to not open and close all at once?

```
#summary {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#summary p.collapse:not(.show) {
    height: 62px !important;
    overflow: hidden;

    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}

#summary p.collapsing {
    min-height: 42px !important;
}

#summary a.collapsed:after  {
    content: '+ Read More';
}

#summary a:not(.collapsed):after {
    content: '- Read Less';
}
```

Following this example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/joserick/pen/ooVPwR)

Comment: Please post a working example that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 2):

Check below snippet. you need to work with diffrent ID's to get desire output.

```css
#summary {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#summary p.collapse:not(.show) {
  height: 42px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

#summary p.collapsing {
  min-height: 42px !important;
}

#summary a.collapsed:after {
  content: '+ Read More';
}

#summary a:not(.collapsed):after {
  content: '- Read Less';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="summary">
        <p class="collapse" id="collapseSummary">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin
          erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu neque. Nam leo massa,
          fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
        </p>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSummary" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSummary"></a>

        <p class="collapse" id="p1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin
          erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu neque. Nam leo massa,
          fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
        </p>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#p1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSummary"></a>

        <p class="collapse" id="p2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin
          erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu neque. Nam leo massa,
          fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
        </p>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#p2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSummary"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a different id for each section and a different href target for each link.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="summary">
        <p class="collapse" id="section1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu neque. Nam leo massa, fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
        </p>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#section1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="section1"></a><br /><br />

        <p class="collapse" id="section2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu neque. Nam leo massa, fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
        </p>
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#section2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="section2"></a>
      </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can doing this by changing IDs**

try this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="summary1">
                <p class="collapse1" id="collapseSummary1">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet.
                    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In
                    hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl
                    tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis
                    massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu
                    neque. Nam leo massa, fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
                </p>
                <a class="collapsed1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSummary1" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="collapseSummary"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="summary2">
                <p class="collapse2" id="collapseSummary2">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc porttitor maximus laoreet.
                    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In
                    hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse venenatis sollicitudin erat in gravida. Sed eget nisl
                    tristique, commodo lectus sit amet, vulputate sem. Cras porttitor lorem ipsum, sit amet iaculis
                    massa feugiat vitae. Curabitur sapien odio, ullamcorper tincidunt interdum vitae, vestibulum eu
                    neque. Nam leo massa, fringilla eget mauris feugiat, auctor suscipit justo.
                </p>
                <a class="collapsed2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseSummary2" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="collapseSummary"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#summary1,
#summary2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#summary1 p.collapse1:not(.show),
#summary2 p.collapse2:not(.show){
    height: 42px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}

#summary1 p.collapsing1,
#summary2 p.collapsing2 {
    min-height: 42px !important;
}

#summary1 a.collapsed1:after,
#summary2 a.collapsed2:after {
    content: '+ Read More';
}

#summary1 a:not(.collapsed1):after,
#summary2 a:not(.collapsed2):after{
    content: '- Read Less';
}
```